# Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS Server not seeing a RAID1 setup by AMD-RAID

Tags: server, system-installation, raid

I am attempting to install Ubuntu Server on a RAID 1 array I setup through my AMD-RAID. This is the legacy RAID that comes with my MSI motherboard which is configured in the BIOS. I have setup the array and AMD-RAID says it's all set, but the installer sees it as two separate hard disks.

Is this a bug in the installer?  Has it been updated in the newer version of Ubuntu?  I have tried all sorts of remedies at this point with no luck.  I would just like to install Ubuntu fresh to my newly created array, any help would be appreciated.